# Как сделать чтобы внутренняя функция получала новый аргумент из внешней?

Tags: javascript

```
function createMessage() {
  var string = '';
  var str;
  console.log('начальное значение аргумента: ' + str);

   return function callback(){
            str = arguments[0];
         console.log('значение аргумента в callback: ' + str);

        if (str !== undefined){
            string += str;
            console.log('значение string в callback: ' + string);
           return callback();
        }
           return string;
  }
  //console.log('вызов callback: ' + callback());
  return string;
}
```

```
console.log(createMessage("Hello")("World!")("how")("are")("you?")());// должно возвратить "Hello World! how are you?
```

У меня же она зацикливается на первом аргументе "Hello", аргумент не изменяется

Comment: Никуда она не зацикливается: `Uncaught TypeError: createMessage(...)(...) is not a function`, что вообще-то логично. `createMessage("Hello" /* argument is ignored */)("World!" /* returns "World!" */)/* not a function */("how")...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function createMessage(st) {
  var string = st || '';
  var str;
   return function callback(){
        str = arguments[0];

    if (str !== undefined){
       string += str;
       return callback;
    }
       return string;
 }
}


 var t = createMessage('hello');
 t('hello')('word')()
```

Попробуйте так. Суть замыкания в том чтобы возвращать не результат callback(),а функцию callback

**Обновлено**

А вообще всё это можно упростить

```js
function createMessage(st) {
  var string = st ||'';
   return function callback(){
             string += arguments[0] || '' ;
        return  arguments[0] ?  callback : string;
  }
}
var test = createMessage('hello ')('word, ')('everybody')();
alert(test);
```

Comment: у тебя, как и у автора вопроса неверная последовательность получается, пропускается первый вызов `createMessage("Hello")`

Comment: Да, спасибо, проправил

Comment: Спасибо друзья.